# How to rewrite $M_1\otimes M_2$ isolating $M_2$?

Tags: matrix-calculus

I have 2 matrices $M_1, M_2$.

Is there a way to rewrite $M_1\otimes M_2$ as $M \cdot M_2$? i.e. $M$ is a matrix that it's being multiplied by $M_2$.

My objective here is to isolate $M_2$ as a product of matrices.

Can we do something similar with $\operatorname{vec}(M_1\otimes M_2)$ as $M\cdot \operatorname{vec}(M_2)$?

Comment: For those who are voting to close. Please give me some feedback. The reasons to vote are too general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following dimensions for the matrices:
$$\eqalign{
 M_1\quad&is\quad(m\times n) \cr
 M_2\quad&is\quad(p\times q) \cr
 M\quad&is\quad(r\times p) \cr
}$$
Then for their products:
$$\eqalign{
 M_1\otimes M_2\quad&is\quad(mp\times nq) \cr
 M\cdot M_2\quad&is\quad(r\times q) \cr
}$$
Note that the final dimensions do not match, except in the trivial case $n=1$.

However, finding a matrix such that 
$${\rm vec}(M_1\otimes M_2)=M\cdot{\rm vec}(M_2)$$
is possible; something along the lines that **Nadiels** has suggested.

Let $c_k$ be the $k^{th}$ **column** of $M_1\,\,$ and let $\,(P,Q)\,$ be the $(p\times p)$ and $(q\times q)$ identity matrices, respectively. Then
$$\eqalign{
M &= \pmatrix{Q\otimes c_1\cr Q\otimes c_2\cr \vdots\cr Q\otimes c_n}\otimes P\cr
}$$

Comment: You're completely right... I never thought about that. I'm a bit dumb... thanks for all the help. ;)

Comment: One thing I didn't understand from the answer of Nadiels is what's $\frac{\partial}{\partial m_i}$...

Comment: Nadiels's derivative zeros out all elements of $M_1$ and $m$ except for the one that corresponds to the $m_i$ component. So it transforms $m$ into a vector from the standard basis ($e_i$), and transforms $M_1$ into a single-entry matrix.

Comment: Greg I always learn with you. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\operatorname{vec}(M_1 \otimes M_2)$ is linear in the entries of  $M_2$, then letting $\mathbf{m} = \operatorname{vec}(M_2)$ you could write
\begin{align}
\operatorname{vec}(M_1 \otimes M_2) &= D \cdot \mathbf{m}_2
\end{align}
where the columns of $D$ are given by
$$
\begin{align}
D_{:, i} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial m_i}\operatorname{vec}(M_1 \otimes M_2) \\
&= \operatorname{vec}\left(M_1 \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial m_i}M_2\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nadiels, Thanks for the answer. However, I don't understand where the derivative comes from...

Comment: Let me reformulate my comment above... What's $m_i$?

Comment: Can't elaborate 'cause phone, but someone else has given you a more complete answer. Basically once you vectorise everything you can write linear transformations as a matrix/vec product using their Jacobian. I was just too lazy to keep track of the change in indices moving to the vectorised form, hence my $\mathbf{m}$

Comment: =OOOOO I would never have thought about something like that!!!!! WOW! =D  thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the problem is to take advantage of the block structure of the Kronecker product $$P = M_1\otimes M_2$$
Simply extract the $(1,1)$-block of the product and divide it by the $(1,1)$ element of the first matrix. Assuming the dimensions of the matrices are 
$$M_1\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n},\quad M_2\in{\mathbb R}^{p\times q}$$
one can isolate the second matrix as follows
$$\eqalign{
M_2 &= \frac{\pmatrix{I_{p} & 0}\Big(M_1\otimes M_2\Big)\pmatrix{I_{q}\cr 0}}{\pmatrix{1&0}M_1\pmatrix{1\cr 0}} \cr
}$$